# CS50 readability 2022

Tags: c, cs50, readability

I am taking CS50x and in PSet 2: Readability throws me the following error when compiling:

[Image of the Error message below, easier to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwe2J.png)

> readability/ $ make readability
> readability.c:52:24: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror,-Wmultichar]
> if ((txt[i] >= '97' && txt[i] <= '122') || (txt[i] >= '65' && txt[i] <= '90'))
> ^
> fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
> 2 errors generated.
> make: *** [: readability] Error 1

I think it has to be an issue that 97 and all other ASCII codes I am using are not recognized as integers, do I need to specifically declare them? If so, how?

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string);
int count_words(string);
int count_sentences(string);

float l;
float w;
float s;

int main(void)
{
    // Ask user for string, store in txt.
    string txt = get_string("Enter your text: ");

    int i = strlen(txt);

    // Convert letters and sentences to avg / 100 w.
    float L = 100 * (l / w);
    float S = 100 * (s / w);

    // Calc coleman-liau index
    int clindex = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S -15.8);

    // Printf "Grade X" if X > 16, printf "Grade 16+".
    if (clindex < 1)
    {
        printf("Grade < 1\n");
    }
    else if (clindex > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", clindex);
    }

}

int count_letters(string txt)
{
    // Count letters
    l = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(txt); i < n; i++)
    {
        // If the txt is between a-z (97 - 122) or A-Z (65 - 90), increase letter count.
        if ((txt[i] >= '97' && txt[i] <= '122') || (txt[i] >= '65' && txt[i] <= '90'))
        {
            l++;
        }
    }
    return l;
}

int count_words(string txt)
{
    // Count words
    w = 1;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(txt); i < n; i++)
    {
        // If there is a space (ascii 32), then increase word count.
        if (txt[i] == 32)
        {
            w++;
        }
    }
    return w;
}

int count_sentences(string txt)
{
    // Count sentences
    s = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n strlen(txt); i < n; i++)
    {
        // If txt is . (period 46), ! (exclamation 33), or ? (question 63), inscrease sentence count.
        if (txt[i] == 46 || txt[i] == 33 || txt[i] == 63)
        {
            s++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Remove the quotes `if ((txt[i] >= 97 && txt[i] <= 122)` since you are comparing char codes which are integers. There is also the `isalpha` func/macro.

Comment: `If the txt is between a-z`?  Use [`islower()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.7), and `isupper()`, etc.  And **don't** use numbers to replace characters - use the character itself, such as `' '` instead of `32`.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like 46, 33 or 63. Use `'.'`, `'!'` and `'?'` instead. Isn't that more readable? And you don't even need that comment anymore. Apparently they don't teach this in cs50.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text (no it's not more readable), post text as __properly formatted__ text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`''` quotes are for single character literals.

`'a'` or `'d'` for example.

`'123'` is more than one character literal.

You probably want to use plain integers instead:

```
(txt[i] >= 97 && txt[i] <= 122)
```

Comment: *You probably want to use plain integers instead*  **NO**.  Use the characters themselves.  Nevermind that `(txt[i] >= 97 && txt[i] <= 122)` is ASCII-only and should be replaced with `islower()` anyway.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem. :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle that would be included in the answer if OP asked for an alternative to the character value checks. OP Question asked for a resolution of the compiler warning/error.

Comment: Replacing `'97'` with `'a'` instead of `97` would also fix the compiler warning and encourage the OP to avoid using magic numbers at the same time.

Comment: @Raildex "readability" is literally in the question title.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed and simplified your code, here is what I got. Seems to work fine.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_letters(string);
int count_words(string);
int count_sentences(string);

float l;
float w;
float s;

int main(void)
{
// Ask user for string, store in txt.
string text = get_string("Text: ");

int i = strlen(text);

// Convert letters and sentences to avg / 100 w.
float L = 100 * (l / w);
float S = 100 * (s / w);

// Calc coleman-liau index
int clindex = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

// Printf "Grade X" if X > 16, printf "Grade 16+".
if (clindex < 1)
{
    printf("Grade < 1\n");
}
else if (clindex > 16)
{
    printf("Grade 16+\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Grade %i\n", clindex);
}
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
// Count letters
l = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
{
    // If the txt is between a-z (97 - 122) or A-Z (65 - 90), increase 
letter count.
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        l++;
    }
}
return l;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
// Count words
w = 1;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
{
    // If there is a space (ascii 32), then increase word count.
    if (isblank(text[i]))
    {
        w++;
    }
}
return w++;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
// Count sentences
s = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
{
    // If txt is . (period 46), ! (exclamation 33), or ? (question 63), 
inscrease sentence count.
    if (ispunct(text[i]))
    {
        s++;
    }
}
return s;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details, such as how or why this solves the problem? Also, it's generally best to not repost all of the code in the answer, just the parts that were changed. You can post full working solutions on https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 0):

This code is the problem

```
if ((txt[i] >= '97' && txt[i] <= '122') || (txt[i] >= '65' && txt[i] <= '90'))
```

Try this

```
if (isalpha(txt[i]))
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C code to me---do you mean `if (isalpha(txt[i]))`?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm more used to Python.